Winter Bash 2015

The end of the year is upon us, and here in Stack Land, that can only
  mean one thing: it's time for Winter Bash 2015!
Event Overview
Winter Bash is a fun, lighthearted event we run every year as a way of
  celebrating the many amazing people who make our communities awesome.
  It's open to any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate.
During Winter Bash, users earn virtual hats by completing certain
  tasks. They're sort of like badges, but they're more visible and less
  permanent. Hats can be "worn" on users' avatars just about anywhere
  avatars show up on the network. Here's an example of what some hats
  looked like last year, taken from the network leaderboard
Of course, we’re rolling out an all-new assortment of hats for this
  year's event, as we have in the past.
The Details
This year's event will start on 14 December 2015 and run up to and
  including 03 January 2016. Users will be able to see all the hats
  they've earned on http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com. That site
  will also have an FAQ to explain how things work.
Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see
  hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option
  available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats
  will go back into storage. 
The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be
  the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

This has been good fun for all involved in the past, but as before we want to give you the opportunity to say, actually no, not this year. Remember though that if you opt out individually you won't see any Hats regardless of what everyone else is seeing :)

I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Winter Bash 2015 has finished and we all had fun.

It's more than acceptable to close questions on meta when the issues they relate to are fixed (in the case of [tag:bug]) or time specific issues (such as this one).

Having had support from the community to run the last three Winter Bash Events on LEGO Answers, I'm sure we won't have any objections this year.

Looks like we're all having a lot of fun with our hats again ;)
